# htaccess - rewritecond issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an htacess file for apache that isn't working properly.

I have a default cactch-all that grabs all requests however it's still catching the matched URL above it (ajax/*). I thought that condition to match urls not containing ajax would stop it but it isn't.

```
RewriteRule ^ajax/(.*)$ process_lite.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^resources/(.*)$ resources/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|jpg|js|gif|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ajax
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ process.php [QSA,L]
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the first rule matches `/ajax/` requests and rewrites it to `/process_lite.php`, thus the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ajax` doesn't match since the URI is now process_lite.php. The regular expression you use won't match anything anyways because REQUEST_URI variable will start with a leading slash. You can try changing the condition to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/process_lite.php
```

Additionally, the "resources" rule doesn't seem to do anything except end rewriting, you could change it to this if that's the goal:

```
RewriteRule ^resources/ - [L]
```